# I am trying to setup banmail for mutt

Tags: bash

I am tring to set up banning mail

```
#!/bin/sh


mail="$(grep "^From:" /dev/stdin | grep -o "[^<> ]\+@.\+\\.[^<>]\+"]" && break

#Give an argument to this command to ban ALL address from this domain

if [-n "$1" ]; then
    domain=$"(echo $mail | cut -d@ -f2)"
    read -r choice </dev/tty
    echo "$choice" | grep -i "^y$" &&
        eval "ssh root@www.rebootcyber.xyz 'echo blacklist_from $domain >> /etc/spamassassin/local.cf;systemctl reload spamassassin &'"
else
    echo Ban only mail address
    echo "Really ban $mail? [y/N]"
    read -r choice </dev/tty
    echo $choice | grep -i "^y$" &&
        eval "ssh root@www.rebootcyber.xyz 'echo blacklist_from $mail >> /etc/spamassassin/local.cf;systemctl reload spamassassin &'"
fi
```

When I run the script I get this error

./banmail: line 18: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./banmail: line 20: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation

Comment: Instead of using `grep` to parse the incoming message, investigate using [`formail`](https://manpage.me/index.cgi?apropos=0&q=formail&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+8.1.0&arch=default&format=html)